# Shell script not opening as desktop application

Tags: scripts, wine, .desktop, executable, ubuntu-dock

I have a shell script which is a wine command to open an .exe file, which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
wine wow.exe -opengl
```

Its only purpose is to run that .exe file. It works if I just double click the script. The location of the script is the same as the .exe file. What I want is to have a desktop application, i.e. an icon I can pin to my dock, which executes this shell script. My desktop application file looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=WoW
Exec=/home/siegmeyer/Documents/WoW/WoW.sh
Icon=/home/siegmeyer/Documents/WoW/WoW.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
Name[en_US]=WoW
```

I can successfully pin the application to my dock, the icon even shows up, but when I click the application, nothing happens, the cursor gets stuck into an infinite loading icon. Have I missed anything?

Comment: What happens if you change the `Exec=` line to `Exec=wine wow.exe -opengl`? Also instead of `wine wow.exe` with `wine "C:\path\to\wow.exe"`?

Comment: I changed `Exec=` to `Exec= wine "C:\home\siegmeyer\Documents\WoW\WoW.exe" -opengl` but it does not work, now nothing loads

Comment: Changing in that way would not work, you need to have the executable in your `.wine` directory and then you'll have to use virtual Windows-like path. What about `Exec=wine "/full/path/to/wow.exe" -opengl`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make sure the script is looking for the executable in the right directory, you could change the call to

```
wine "$(realpath "$(dirname "$0")")/wow.exe" -opengl
```

This will insert the absolute path of the script (and thus the exe) into the call. It would work without the quotes for paths that don't contain whitespace, but I recommend to keep them in case you move the directory.